# Replace all characters bigger than f

Tags: java, string

I use normally this command to replace characters in one String

```
myString.replace("f", "a").trim()
```

but this time I want to create a Hex String so I want to replace all characters that are bigger than `f` with the character `a`.
Is it possible to adapt this command ?

Comment: *"...I want to create a Hex String so I want to replace all characters that are bigger than `f` with the character `a`"* Um....why would you do that?

Comment: You can use a regex and [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an upper bounding character (I'll use `z` as an example), you could use a regular expression with [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
myString = myString.trim().replaceAll("[g-z]", "a");
```

The regular expression `[g-z]` means "any character `g` through `z` inclusive", see [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for details.

You may want to create the regular expression explicitly rather than relying on `replaceAll`'s default version, if you want case-insensitivity for instance:

```
myString = Pattern.compile("[g-z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                  .matcher(myString.trim())
                  .replaceAll("a");
```

Comment: ...with thanks to [Nikolas Charalambidis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3764965/nikolas-charalambidis) for questioning my original, incorrect answer and prompting me to check the docs and, not finding support there, try it; and to [Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) for pointing out the *other* error in my previous answer in that I started with `f` rather than `g`! Also [Tom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) who independently checked the docs and tried it at the same time I was.

Comment: Easier way to add `CASE_INSENSITIVE`: `replaceAll("(?i)[g-z]", "a")`. --- Also, as I mentioned in comment to your old answer, a better choice might be `replaceAll("[^0-9A-Fa-f]", "a")`, so all invalid *characters* are replaced, not just lowercase g-z *letters*.

Comment: @Andreas: I was answering the question asked (*"all characters that are bigger than f..."*). It seems an odd requirement (I flagged that up in a comment on the question), but replacing all invalid characters with `a` is just as odd. :-) The `Pattern` example wasn't *just* for case insensitivity, but to point out how to have more control over the regex *in general*.

Comment: I do agree that replacing bad characters with `a` is *very* odd. `f` or `0` would seem more obvious, but would still be odd. Removing them might be ok, but really it should fail on bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to do so `[^a-f0-9]` would select any characters not allowed in a string representing a hexadecimal number. You would need to replace all occurrences of this group by your desired value.

Comment: Can't use `+` if each invalid character should be replaced by `a`. Also don't need a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the characters of your string, and replace those greater than f with what you want;

```
StringBuilder newString=new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            char c = myString.charAt(i);
            if (c > 'f') {
                newString.append('a');
            } else {
                newString.append(c);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would be faster and more direct to just call `arr = myString.toCharArray()`, fix the characters in the array, then call `new String(arr)`.